# Java Add() and Multiply() methods returning 0/0 and 1/1?

Tags: java, methods, addition, fractions, multiplication

For homework I'm supposed to use the following Driver to output the sum and the product of two input fractions, both as a fraction and a double.

The problem is that the Add() method I created keeps returning "0/0 NaN" and the Multiply() method keeps returning "1/1 1.0".  I've been trying a lot of different things but I can't figure out how to get the methods to overwrite the new fractions from the driver.

Here is my driver:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FractionDriver {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
     Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in); 
     Fraction c, d, x; // Fraction objects 

     System.out.println("Enter numerator; then denominator."); 
     c = new Fraction(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt()); 
     c.print(); 

     System.out.println("Enter numerator; then denominator."); 
     d = new Fraction(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt()); 
     d.print(); 

     x = new Fraction(); // create a fraction for number 0 

     System.out.println("Sum:"); 
     x.add(c).add(d); 
     x.print(); 
     x.printAsDouble(); 

     x = new Fraction(1, 1); // create a fraction for number 1 

     System.out.println("Product:"); 
     x.multiply(c).multiply(d); 
     x.print(); 
     x.printAsDouble(); 

     System.out.println("Enter numerator; then denominator."); 
     x = new Fraction(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt()); 
     x.printAsDouble(); 

     } // end main 

}  //end class
```

Here is my Fraction class:

```
package ch6;

public class Fraction 
{
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    //*************************************************************

    public Fraction()
    {

    }

    //*************************************************************

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }



//**************************************************************

    public int getNumerator()
    {
        return this.denominator;
    }

    //**************************************************************

    public int getDenominator()
    {
        return this.denominator;
    }

    //**************************************************************

    public Fraction add(Fraction c)
    {
        denominator = this.getDenominator() * c.getDenominator();
        numerator = this.getNumerator() * c.getDenominator() + c.getNumerator() * this.getDenominator();
        return new Fraction (numerator, denominator);
    }

    //**************************************************************

    public Fraction multiply(Fraction c)
    {
        int productNumerator = this.numerator * c.numerator;
        int productDenominator = this.denominator * c.denominator;
        return new Fraction(productNumerator, productDenominator);
    }


    //**************************************************************

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(this.numerator + "/" + this.denominator);
    }

    //**************************************************************

    public void printAsDouble()
    {
        System.out.println((double) this.numerator / this.denominator);
    }

}
```

Comment: `getNumerator { return this.denominator}`? See anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly representing the value 0 with a numerator and denominator of `0` each.  That value, `0/0`, is indeterminate in math and will produce `NaN` in floating-point operations.

Try a mathematically correct zero, represented as 0 for the numerator and 1 for the denominator.

```
// Creates zero.
public Fraction()
{
    this.numerator = 0;  // This line is unnecessary, as default is 0.
    this.denominator = 1;
}
```

Additionally, in your `add` method, you are returning a new `Fraction`, but you are also changing the `numerator` and `denominator` of the current `Fraction`.  Like `multiply`, you'll want to create local variables to store the new numerator and new denominator, to avoid changing the current `Fraction`.

```
// Declare them as "int" local variables.
int denominator = this.getDenominator() * c.getDenominator();
int numerator = this.getNumerator() * c.getDenominator() +
               c.getNumerator() * this.getDenominator();
```

Incidentally, as @MarcB already stated in a comment, this is wrong:

```
public int getNumerator()
{
    return this.denominator;
}
```

Change it to return the numerator!

Comment: You can also throw an exception or print an error message if denominator is 0.

Comment: Based on how the fractions are used in `main`, I think the instance variables should be changed and `add` and multiply should return `this`.